# Can surf in ipv6 pages but cannot ping or curl them

Tags: networking, debian, ping, ipv6, curl

I have a debian linux virtual machine in virtual box using a bridged connection.
Inside the debian virtual machine, I can surf any web page whether it is ipv4 or ipv6, I can ping and curl ipv4, but, I cannot ping ipv6.

This is my interface:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 192.168.1.103  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
inet6 2a01:c50e:888d:cf00:1b53:a4cc:dfb7:980d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
inet6 fe80::686d:8be3:fd65:663c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
ether 08:00:27:38:6c:27  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
RX packets 9024  bytes 5239327 (4.9 MiB)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 4986  bytes 710662 (694.0 KiB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: What errors are you getting?